# React Native Firebase messaging background notification doesn't shown in notification center in Android 13

Tags: android, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

The push notification message is received but not shown in notification center of my Android 13 phone when I send push notification no matter from my server or FCM tester. It works fine in my Android 12 phone.

Here is my Android related code:

In **AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS"/>
```

In **build.gradle**:

```
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33
        androidXCore = "1.0.2"
```

RN related code:

```
      messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async remoteMessage => {
        console.log('Background notification:',JSON.stringify(remoteMessage));
      });

      messaging().onMessage(async remoteMessage => {
        console.log(remoteMessage);
      });

      messaging().onNotificationOpenedApp(remoteMessage => {
        console.log('onNotificationOpenedApp');
      });

      messaging()
        .getInitialNotification()
        .then(async remoteMessage => {
          console.log('getInitialNotification');
```

And I get the FCM token and add the following permission request when application started:

```
const requestNotificationPermission = async () => {
  const result = await request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);
  return result;
};

const checkNotificationPermission = async () => {
  const result = await check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);
  return result;
};

export const requestPushNotificationPermission = async () => {
  const checkPermission = await checkNotificationPermission();
  if (checkPermission !== RESULTS.GRANTED) {
    const request = await requestNotificationPermission();
    if (request === RESULTS.GRANTED) {
      console.log('Push notification is allowed');
    }
  }
};

const getFCMToken = async () => {
  try {
    let token = await messaging().getToken()
    if (token) {
      console.log('FCM token:', token);
    }
  } catch(error) {
    console.error(error)
  }
};
```

I'm able to receive notification like this when application in background:

> Background notification: {"notification":{"android":{"sound":"mySound","smallIcon":"myicon"},"body":"You have been xxxxx","title":"xxx"},"sentTime":1695283420621,"ttl":2419200,"data":{"TemplateId":"null","HyperLink":"xxxxx","HyperLinkType":"xxxx","NotificationMsgId":"1234-9b50-40a8-b284-daaa7a60d9bf"},"messageId":"0:16935283420814699%e0a343f4e0a343a4","from":"613166636902","collapseKey":"xxxxx"}

It will be shown in notification center when I tested with my Android 12 phone. But nothing is shown in notification center when I tested with my Android 13 phone. What could be the reason?

Comment: Were you able to find a solution of your problem? I am also having same problem. Please respond.

Answer (score -1):

In your `src/index.js` file, please add following part.

```
import {PermissionsAndroid} from 'react-native';
```

PermissionsAndroid.request(PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.POST_NOTIFICATIONS);